# Jquery show/hide confusion

Tags: jquery

I have implemented this many times before but I cannot figure out why it is not working for me this time.  If there is not content being pulled then I want the div to hide.

FRONT-END

```
 <div class="title">
    <h2>PRESS</h2>
    <?php echo $info['man_press']; ?>
</div>
```

SCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".title").each(function() {
  if ($(this).find("p").length > 0) {
     $(this).show();
   }else{
     $(this).hide();
   }
 });
});
```

Comment: There are no `p` tags - unless `$info['man_press']` outputs one.

Comment: it's working here [link](http://jsfiddle.net/kBL4w/1/)

Comment: @EduardoQuintana assuming there is a `p` in `.title`

Comment: $info['man_press] will output a paragraph if there is content to be pulled.

Comment: There is no reason for this not to work then. Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: @NickBalistreri your code should work assuming there is a paragraph tag inside .title and jquery is included on your page. Do you have an example page to demonstrate your issue?

Comment: Use `View Source` to confirm that the PHP is producing what you expect. The problem is most likely in `$info['man_press']`

Answer (score 0):

***Try with this code***

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".title").each(function() {
  if ($(this).find("p").length > 0) {
     $(this).show();
   }else{
     $(this).hide();
   }
 });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="title">
    <h2>PRESS</h2>
    <p>hello</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Remove p tag and try it, it will hide entire div **

Comment: How is this different to what the OP has, other than hard coding the `p` tag?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan if php code (<?php echo $info['man_press']; ?>) is returning the value appending with p tags and content, then above code works. Value which is appearing from the server might have missed the p tags.

Comment: Posting what is essentially "Your code works for me" is helpful, but it should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan sorry i have not read your previous comment. it is right that p tags  is missing from the values.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys but I checked my Jquery version and it was super old.  A quick update and things work perfectly now.  Maximum noob